# What is the difference between Viterbi CYK and Probabilistic CYK algorithm, Is there any differences?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, viterbi, cyk

I think they are the same concept, 
https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs498jh/Slides/Lecture10.pdf
Probabilistic CYK algorithm is used the viterbi algorithm to parse, is my concept is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. You can consider weight CKY is equivalent to Viterbi for parsing. You can see the lecture on Viterbi and Statistical parsing with PCFG from [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~kc2wc/teaching/NLP16/syllabus.html). However, Viterbi algorithm can be used to find the most likely sequence of hidden states and probabilistic CYK algorithm is specifically designed for tagging/parsing.